# JavaScript return html content in that specific code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
var currentusername = Discourse.User.currentProp('username');

if (currentusername == "crazy-geek") {


    api.createWidget('admin-menu', {
        tagName: 'div.admin-panel',

        panelContents() {
            return "hello " + currentusername;
        },

        html() {
            return this.attach('menu-panel', {
                contents: () => this.panelContents()
            });
        },

        clickOutside() {
            this.sendWidgetAction('toggleAdmin');
        }
    });

    api.decorateWidget('header-icons:after', function (helper) {
        const headerState = helper.widget.parentWidget.state;
        let contents = [];
        contents.push(helper.attach('header-dropdown', {
            title: 'admin-menu',
            icon: 'asterisk',
            active: headerState.adminVisible,
            iconId: 'toggle-admin-menu',
            action: 'toggleAdmin',
        }));
        if (headerState.adminVisible) {
            contents.push(helper.attach('admin-menu'));
        }
        return contents;
    });

    api.attachWidgetAction('header', 'toggleAdmin', function () {
        this.state.adminVisible = !this.state.adminVisible;
    });

};
```

I need to return html content in the following part:

```
        panelContents() {
            return "hello " + currentusername;
        },
```

So the part "hello " + currentusername; needs to be replaced with specific html content, as for my example that will be a small menu with some links inside.

How can I archieve that?

Comment: `return "hello <select name='foo'><option ...></option><option ...></option></select>";`

Comment: Just put whatever HTML you want there.

Comment: `return "<YourHTMLhere>"

Comment: I have tried that out, it ends up showing me that: hello <span>Test</span>